# Have conversion error in my dynamic SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to build a dynamic SQL statement and I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is the statement:

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(128) = '2451,2452'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @userid NVARCHAR(50) = 'myUserId'

SET @sql = N'UPDATE MyLogTable SET MessageType = ''F'', LastUpdatedBy = ''' + @userId + ''',
        LastUpdated = ''' + GETDATE() + ' WHERE id IN(' + @param + ')
```

What's wrong with this statement?

Comment: I've added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax and error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing apostrophe at the end of the date:

```
LastUpdated = ''' + GETDATE() + ' WHERE...
```

will generate the following SQL:

```
LastUpdated = ' 2019-12-08 11:15 WHERE...
```

Please note that this will update the LastUpdated value to the time and date when the dynamic SQL was generated, which is usually a pretty good accuracy but a more accurate statement would be to have the `GETDATE()` as a part of the dynamic query itself (which also makes a simpler, less error-prone SQL statement.
You should always print the dynamic SQL before executing it, to make sure you don't have such mistakes.
Also, you are concatenating the parameters into your SQL statement, making it vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

While we're on the subject, I suggest reading my blog post called [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server-%EF%BB%BF/) - where I explain how to safely create dynamic SQL statements that avoids the dangerous of SQL Injection, as well as one more tip on how to generate readable, maintainable dynamic SQL statements.

A safer dynamic SQL would be this:

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(128) = '2451,2452',
        @sql NVARCHAR(4000),
        @userid NVARCHAR(50) = 'myUserId',
        @Tab nchar(1) = NCHAR(9),
        @LineBreak nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @sql = 
    N'UPDATE MyLogTable '+ @LineBreak +
    N'SET MessageType = ''F'', '+ @LineBreak +
    N'LastUpdatedBy = @userId , '+ @LineBreak +
    N'LastUpdated = GETDATE() '+ @LineBreak + 
    N'WHERE id IN(' + @param + ')';

PRINT @SQL

--EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @Sql, N'@userid nvarchar(50)', @userid
```

Note this this still doesn't handle the `@param` concatenation.
Since this is an `IN` operator, I would advise to use a table valued parameter instead of a comma-delimited string.

Assuming a user defined table type called Ids with a single id int column:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ids AS Table(Id int) 
GO
```

Here's how a safe dynamic SQL statement would look like:

```
DECLARE @param dbo.Ids;
INSERT INTO @Param (Id) Values (2451),(2452);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000),
        @userid NVARCHAR(50) = 'myUserId',
        @Tab nchar(1) = NCHAR(9),
        @LineBreak nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @sql = 
    N'UPDATE MyLogTable '+ @LineBreak +
    N'SET MessageType = ''F'', '+ @LineBreak +
    N'LastUpdatedBy = @userId , '+ @LineBreak +
    N'LastUpdated = GETDATE() '+ @LineBreak + 
    N'WHERE id IN(SELECT Id FROM @param)';

PRINT @SQL

--EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @Sql, N'@userid nvarchar(50), @param dbo.Ids', @userid
```